# Double style and double colour line in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

in my document i have a lot of lines like this:

[image: LineExample]

I usually do this with a code like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm]
 \node (a) {};
 \node (b) [right of=a] {};
 \draw[red] (a) -- (b);
 \draw[blue, decorate, decoration={snake}] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I thought it would be easier if i defined an appropriate tikzstyle, so i tried with something like:

```
\tikzstyle{LL} =[draw, postaction={decorate, blue, draw}, decoration={snake}]
```

but i can't find a way to make the straight line red... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `\tikzstyle{LL} =[draw=red, postaction={decorate, blue, draw}, decoration={snake}]`

Comment: Also, `\tikzstyle` syntax is deprecated. A better approach: `\tikzset{LL/.style ={draw=red, postaction={decorate, blue, draw}, decoration={snake}}}`

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
\tikzset{
LL/.style={
  draw=red, 
  postaction={decorate,draw=blue},
  decoration={snake}
  }
}
```

notice the change to the more modern `\tikzset` syntax. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\tikzset{
LL/.style={
  draw=red, 
  postaction={decorate,draw=blue},
  decoration={snake}
  }
}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 5cm]
 \node (a) {};
 \node (b) [right of=a] {};
 \draw[LL] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]